# React useEffect does not fetch paramter into React useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rerender

Why does my article state doesnt have the same Parameter like my cart.filter element.
What am I doing wrong, using the useState Hook.

```
  const [article, setArticle] = useState();
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
  const { id } = useParams();
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCartAndPrice = async () => {
      const { sess } = await ApiClientShoppingCart.getCart();
      setCart(sess.cart);
    };
    setArticle(cart.filter((e) => e.id === id));
    fetchCartAndPrice();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      {console.log(cart.filter((e) => e.id === id))}
      {console.log(article)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the moment that you are trying set the articles don't have carts yet. You need wait the cart update creating an exclusive useEffect to cart. Something like this:

```
const [article, setArticle] = useState();
const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
const { id } = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchCartAndPrice = async () => {
  const { sess } = await ApiClientShoppingCart.getCart();
    setCart(sess.cart);
  };

  fetchCartAndPrice();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  setArticle(cart.filter((e) => e.id === id));
}, [cart]);

return (
  <div>
    {console.log(cart.filter((e) => e.id === id))}
    {console.log(article)}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you trigger your function `setArticle()` the async function which fetch the cart didn't finished yet ... So it can't "filter" the (still empty) cart ...

You need to execute that filter thing after the cart is set :

```
const [article, setArticle] = useState();
const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
const { id } = useParams();
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchCartAndPrice = async () => {
    const { sess } = await ApiClientShoppingCart.getCart();
    setCart(sess.cart);
  };
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  // --> ensure we are not in the "init step"
  if (cart.length) {
    setArticle(cart.filter((e) => e.id === id));

    // Not sur where this one belongs ... :
    fetchCartAndPrice();
  }
}, [cart]);

return (
  <div>
    {console.log(cart.filter((e) => e.id === id))}
    {console.log(article)}
  </div>
);
```

Another maner to do so is to set the article at the same place of the cart :

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchCartAndPrice = async () => {
    const { sess } = await ApiClientShoppingCart.getCart();
    setCart(sess.cart);
    setArticle(sess.cart.filter((e) => e.id === id));
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: if I use your second option (which I would prefer), the setState after the useEffect ist undefined... I dont understand what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Gabriel Furlan gave a great solution.
I would use the async declaration at the top level of the useEffect hook.
Ex.

```
const [article, setArticle] = useState();
const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
const { id } = useParams();

useEffect(async () => {
  const sess = await ApiClientShoppingCart.getCart();
  setCart(sess.cart);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  setArticle(cart.filter((e) => e.id === id));
}, [cart]);

return (
  <div>
    {console.log(cart.filter((e) => e.id === id))}
    {console.log(article)}
  </div>
);
```